# Boost Bimap to insert_or_modify

Tags: c++, boost, bimap

STL map "[]" operator can insert new entries or modify existing entries.

```
map<string, string> myMap;
myMap["key1"] = "value1";
myMap["key1"] = "value2";
```

I am rewriting some code with boost::bimap which was implemented by STL map. Is there an easy way to keep the STL "[]" behavior? I found I have to write below 7 lines code to replace the original STL map code (1 line!).

```
bimap<string, string>::left_iterator itr = myBimap.left.find("key1");
if (itr != myBimap.left.end()) {
    myBimap.left.replace_data(itr, "value2");
} 
else {
    myBimap.insert(bimap<string, string>::value_type("key1", "value2"));
}
```

I was wondering if there's an utility function like boost::bimap::insert_or_modify().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [**Boost.Bimap documentation**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/boost_bimap/the_tutorial/differences_with_standard_maps.html#boost_bimap.the_tutorial.differences_with_standard_maps.operator_____and_at__) shows how mimic a `std::map` including its `operator[]` by using `set_of` and `list_of` for the `bimap` template arguments:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/bimap.hpp>
#include <boost/bimap/set_of.hpp>
#include <boost/bimap/list_of.hpp>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;    
    map<string, string> myMap;
    myMap["key1"] = "value1";
    myMap["key1"] = "value2";
    for (auto&& elem : myMap)
        std::cout << "{" << elem.first << ", " << elem.second << "}, ";
    std::cout << "\n";

    using namespace boost::bimaps;
    bimap<set_of<string>, list_of<string>> myMap2;
    myMap2.left["key1"] = "value1";
    myMap2.left["key1"] = "value2";
    for (auto&& elem : myMap2.left)
        std::cout << "{" << elem.first << ", " << elem.second << "}, ";
    std::cout << "\n";

    auto res1 = myMap2.left.find("key1");
    std::cout << "{" << res1->first << ", " << res1->second << "} \n";    
}
```

[**Live Example.**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2fd433dc40554d59)

**UPDATE**: the above code also allows left-searches. However, a right-search is not possible in combination with the required `operator[]` syntax. The reason is that `operator[]` modifications can only be done with a **mutable** right-view (such `list_of` or `vector_of`). OTOH, right-searches can only be done from **immutable** `set_of` and `unordered_set_of` and their multi- cousins.

Comment: What if I also need `myMap2.left.find("foo")` and `myMap2.right.find("bar")`? Looks like `list_of` doesn't provide `find()` member function. And declaring **myMap2** as `bimap<set_of<string>, set_of<string>>` got a compilation error due to using `[]` operator.